# Assembly - add words with EAX

Tags: assembly

I have the next code:

```
Var1: dw 0xFE
Var2: db 0xAB
Var3: db 0xBC
```

And I want add one to each of the variable.

As I understood, the memory looks like this: `FE00ABBC`

and for that, The next command should work:

```
mov eax, 0x010000101
add dword [Var1], eax
```

But this one is working:

```
mov eax, 0x01010001
add dword [Var1], eax
```

Why? Thanks.

Comment: you should check that your endian-ness is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in that you didn't take account for the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the architecture.

Comment: That won't solve the problem  The problem is that he put the three variables in the wrong order in memory.  What you did is exactly what he did, except you use `ebx` as an intermediary.

Comment: Removed last part because indeed it doesn't solve it. However i think the problem is the endianness as I stated.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your memory map is wrong.  I would interpret it like this:

```
 BCAB00FE
 ^      ^
 |      |
MSB    LSB
```

Which would exactly explain the behavior you see.

Comment: Well, actually he didn't indicate where the low end of his memory map is, I just assumed low left (usually byte are read from left to right... at least here). After a second look I see that you assumed the opposite.

Comment: @drhirsch: My assumption is upheld by the fact that it explains the behavior the OP sees.  The problem is that he's reading it left-to-right in the memory map, but right-to-left in eax.

Answer (score 0):

Your achitecure is low-endian, the lowest significant bits are at the lowest memory address. This is reverse to the usual western writing direction.

The memory looks exactly as you described, but when it ist loaded, seemingly gets reversed:

```
`FE 00 AB BC`
 low    high    address

 mov eax, 0x1010001

 01 00 01 01
 low    high    byte in eax
```

So the content of eax is now `01010001` if you write it from left to write.

The problem arises because the order in which you write numerical constants in the assembler source is different from the order in which the bytes actually are stored in memory.